# Cannot install bootcamp because of disk error, but disk utility says it's fine?

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

[image]

I'm trying to partition for bootcamp but it fails because of that error. I ran disk utility's first aid multiple times. And it's always fine.

What do I do?

Edit:

[image]

My mac is the newest imac from this year. The windows I'm trying to install is Windows 10 Pro x64.

[image]

Comment: From the Terminal application, run the commands `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list`, then post the outputs. Also include model/year of your Mac. The version of macOS and the version of Windows you are attempting to install. Also, you should remove all unnecessary external disks while trying to install Windows. You also might try running First Aid on the Macintosh HD while booted to Recovery Mode.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for your help. I updated the OP with the info. I removed all external disks and tried again, did not help. I'll try running first aid in recovery next.

Comment: Recovery mode first aid wasn't any different.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably asking the wrong question. If I were you, I would be asking about the 296.6 GB of free space which appears in your Logical Volume group. If you can get most of this free space added to you Logical Volume, the bootcamp install would probably work.

According to the accepted answer to [How do I recover free space from my logical volume group?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306199/how-do-i-recover-free-space-from-my-logical-volume-group), you would probably be better off recreating the Fusion Drive, instead of attempting a repair.